# VUE-how to change the style by typing the name of it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-visualization

I tried to change the part of the style attribute by input the number or any details in the text input. However, I want to replace the entire object specifying the style as below.
But it only allows me to change the part of the object only.

What whould I do?

> html

```
  <div>
    <label> Type width</label>
    <input type="text" v-on:keydown.enter= 'defst($event.target.value)'>
    <div :style='stylename'>kkk</div>
  </div>
```

> js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {

    narrow:{
      backgroundColor:'lemonchiffon',
      width:150+'px'
    },
    medium:{
      backgroundColor:'yellow',
      width:250+'px'
    },
    large:{
      backgroundColor:'organge',
      width: 350+'px'
    },
    xlarge:{
      backgroundColor:'red',
      width: 500 +'px'
    },
    stylename:''

  },
  methods: {

  defst(x){
    console.log(x);
    this.stylename=x
  }

}
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if the point is to enter `narrow`, `medium` etc ... change to `:style='this[stylename]'` - you may also want to spell `orange` correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this part:

```
  defst(x){
    console.log(x);
    this.stylename=x
  }
```

to

```
  defst(x){
    console.log(x);
    this.stylename=this[x]
  }
```

Comment: that would work too, but then `stylename` is a misleading property name :D

Comment: @JaromandaX I check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-https-szus3 and it works, your solution works too :)

Comment: I know they both work, but I like my variables to be accurate descriptions of their intended use :p in this case I'd rename `stylename` to `style` :p

Comment: @BeHappy Thank you so much!! Why do I need to go with this[x]? cause I gussed
x itself is enough to refer the value from v-model. what is this[x]???

Comment: because `x` is only e.g. narrow, but you want to refer to data on component, so you need `this`. and this[x] for e.g. `narrow` will convert to this.narrow